# Laravel でデータ保存時にエラーが出てしまう

Tags: php, laravel, aws-cloud9

Laravelでクイズアプリを作っているのですが、問題を出すユーザー側がタイトル、問題、ヒント、答えを書込み、保存し、他のユーザーが答えを記入し、合っていたら保存、表示するというものです。この作業で答えを書き込む、保存の部分でエラーが出ます。理由を教えていただけないでしょうか？

テーブル情報 (ER図)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhvyAhPeAr3mq8zV7OMI6Yu9DJrDSE4T/view?usp=sharing
現在、必要最低限であるUsers、Questions、Answersの3つだけを作っています。
コードはGitHubにあります。
https://github.com/Kento-Hongo/Fermat_Letters.git

Comment: 具体的なエラーの内容を質問に含めてください。

Comment: すいません。エラー文はこちらになります。 Undefined variable $answer –

Answer (score 0):

$question 変数が宣言されてないからです．
おそらく ＄answer の間違いではないでしょうか？

Request になにが入ってくるか全く分からないので，とりあえずこんな感じ．

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $model = new Answer();
  $model->answer = $request->input('answer');
  $model->question_id = $request->input('question_id');
  $model->user_id = Auth::id();
  $model->save();

  return redirect('/answers', $answer->id);
}
```

もちろん fill() や create() でもできます

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: すいません。エラー文はこちらになります。
Undefined variable $answer

Comment: どのクラス，どの行で起こっているかまで教えていただけないと結局エスパー回答になってしまいます